# Why the parameters of this Google Apps Script are not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, parameters, google-apps-script, arguments

I'm having trouble setting the parameters for the second function (this one `function findDate (text, word)`) of the code below. Rather than use this code:

```
if (text2[text2.length - 2] === word) {
   date = text2[text2.length - 1];
```

I would like to use this other:

```
if (text2[text2.length - position_word] === word){
   date = text2[text2.length - position_date];
```

So I could invoke this function in different contexts.
However, when I add two more parameters to this function, like this `function findDate (text, word, position_word, position_date)` , it just doesn't work. And I can not understand what goes wrong (log messages seem to be OK). You are able to see what is wrong? What is the JS function property that I'm missing here?

```
function setColumnIfromG() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var input = s.getRange(2, 7, s.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      output.push([ findDate(input[i][0], 'common term') ]);
   // output.push([ findDate(input[i][0], 'common term', -2, -1) ]);
      s.getRange(2, 9, output.length, 1).setValues(output);
    }
 }

function findDate (text, word){
//function findDate (text, word, position_word, position_date){
  Logger.log('text = '+ text);
  var text1 = text.split(".Date");
  Logger.log("text1 = "+ text1);
  var date = 'no date informed';
  for (var i=0; i<text1.length; i++) {
    var text2 = text1[i].split(" ");
    Logger.log("text2 = " + text2);
    Logger.log("text2[text2.length - 2] = " + text2[text2.length - 2]);
    Logger.log("text2[text2.length - 1] = " + text2[text2.length - 1]);

//    Logger.log("text2.length = " + text2[text2.length]);
//    Logger.log("position_word = " + position_word);
//    Logger.log("position_date = " + position_date);

    if (text2[text2.length - 2] === word){
      date = text2[text2.length - 1];
//    if (text2[text2.length - position_word] === word) {
//        date = text2[text2.length - position_date];
    }
      else {
      date = 'no date informed';
      }
   }
   return date;
}
```

PS -  I know that the "position date" is not -1 but `text2.length - 1`. So, "position date" is really `text2.length - position_date` and not position_date. I put this name only to remember-me of what this -1 is related to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your two param version you have the code

```
date = text2[text2.length - 1];
```

In your four param version you have the code

```
date = text2[text2.length - position_date];
```

But you pass -1 in to the function as the value of the new `position_date` param

I'll sit and wait here looking at you until the penny drops 8-)

Comment: Hi, @Drew, I know that the "position date" is not `-1` but `[text2.length - 1]`. So, "position date" is really `[text2.length - position_date]` and not `position_date`. I put this name only to remember-me of what this `-1` is related to. But, in any case, the function with 4 param doesn't work when `position_date` is `-1`. If the penny coin isn't this, please, help it drop in my mind! =)

Comment: Hi mate - sorry to not point it out. If you want `text2[text2.length - position_date]` to be the same as `text2[text2.length - 1]`, then you should pass 1 in as `position_date`. You are passing -1 in as `position_date`, so your `text2[text2.length - position_date]` is the same as `text2[text2.length + 1]` which will give you all sorts of problems. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ha ha - no problems... we've all been there - we're only human!